# Spring Batch restart functionality not working when using @StepScope

Tags: spring-batch

I want to use Spring Batch (v3.0.9) restart functionality so that when `JobInstance` restarted the process step reads from the last failed chunk point forward. My restart works fine as long as I don't use `@StepScope` annotation to my `myBatisPagingItemReader` bean method.
I was using `@StepScope` so that i can do late binding to get the `JobParameters` in my `myBatisPagingItemReader` bean method  `@Value("#{jobParameters['run-date']}"))`
If I use `@StepScope` annotation on `myBatisPagingItemReader()` bean method the restart does not work as it creates new instance (scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader).
If i use stepscope, is it possible for my myBatisPagingItemReader to set the read.count from the last failure to get restart working?

I have explained this issue with example below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader,
        ItemProcessor<Model, Model> itemProcessor,
         ItemWriter<Model> itemWriter) {

         return stepBuilderFactory.get("data-load")
            .<Model, Model>chunk(10)
            .reader(myBatisPagingItemReader)
            .processor(itemProcessor)
             .writer(itemWriter)
             .listener(itemReadListener())
             .listener(new JobParameterExecutionContextCopyListener())
             .build();
   }
   @Bean
   public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, @Qualifier("step1") 
               Step step1) {
           return jobBuilderFactory.get("load-job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(step1)
            .listener(jobExecutionListener())
            .build();
   }
   @Bean
   @StepScope
   public ItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader(
         SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory,
         @Value("#{JobParameters['run-date']}") String runDate) 
  {
     MyBatisPagingItemReader<Model> reader = new 
     MyBatisPagingItemReader<>();
     Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
     parameterValues.put("runDate", runDate);
     reader.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
     reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
     reader.setQueryId("query");
     return reader;
   }
}
```

Restart Example when I use `@Stepscope` annotation to `myBatisPagingItemReader()`, the reader is fetching 5 records and I have chunk size(commit-interval) set to 3.

Job Instance - 01 - Job Parameter - 01/02/2019.
chunk-1:
- process record-1
- process record-2
- process record-3
writer - writes all 3 records
chunk-1 commit successful

chunk-2:
process record-4
process record-5 - Throws and exception
Job completes and set to 'FAILED' status

Now the Job is Restarted again using same Job Parameter.
Job Instance - 01 - Job Parameter - 01/02/2019.
chunk-1:
process record-1
process record-2
process record-3
writer - writes all 3 records
chunk-1 commit successful

chunk-2:
process record-4
process record-5 - Throws and exception
Job completes and set to 'FAILED' status

The `@StepScope` annotation on `myBatisPagingItemReader()` bean method creates a new instance , see below log message.
Creating object in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader
Registered destruction callback in scope=step, name=scopedTarget.myBatisPagingItemReader
As it is new instance it start the process from start, instead of starting from chunk-2.

If i don't use `@Stepscope`, it restarts from chunk-2 as the restarted job step sets - MyBatisPagingItemReader.read.count=3.

Comment: When you use `StepScope` and the job fails the first attempt, can you please share the value of `read.count` from the step execution context before the restart? How do you restart the job? Even if there is a new instance of the reader, this instance will be initialized with the `read.count` from the last (failed) step execution and continue from there. I don't see how using `StepScope` or not can impact restartability.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are returning an `ItemReader` instead of the fully qualified class (`MyBatisPagingItemReader`) or at least `ItemStreamReader`.  When you use Spring Batch's step scope, we create a proxy to allow for late initialization.  The proxy is based on the return type of the method (`ItemReader` in your case).  The issue you are running into is that because the proxy is of `ItemReader`, Spring Batch does not know that your bean also implements `ItemStream` and it is *that* interface that enables restartability.  By default, Spring Batch will automatically register all beans of type `ItemStream` for you (you can also explicitly register the beans yourself, but it's typically not needed).

To address your issue, the following should work (note the change in the return type):

```
   @Bean
   @StepScope
   public MyBatisPagingItemReader<Model> myBatisPagingItemReader(
         SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory,
         @Value("#{JobParameters['run-date']}") String runDate) {

     MyBatisPagingItemReader<Model> reader = 
         new MyBatisPagingItemReader<>();

     Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
     parameterValues.put("runDate", runDate);

     reader.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
     reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
     reader.setQueryId("query");

     return reader;
   }
```

This is why it is my recommendation that where possible, when using `@Bean` annotated methods, you should return the most concrete type possible to allow Spring to help as much as possible.

Comment: Not using concrete type reader was the issue. As suggested i now used concrete type reader and the restart is now working fine. the reader is now picking the  last reader.read.count from the last point of failure.  I accept this solution.