# Spring Batch JobOperator.restart start a new job instance and don't resume job from the last chunk but just from last step

Tags: spring-batch

```
  jobOperator.restart(JobExecutionId)
```

starts a new job instance and don't resume job from the last chunk but just from last step. I need to resume the job from the last chunk written.

My reader is a custom RestReader that count first the total of items to process and then read this exact number from api. I'm using @StepScope annotation because I need custom variables in custom reader

[Spring Batch restart functionality not working when using @StepScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513559/spring-batch-restart-functionality-not-working-when-using-stepscope).

Is it possible to resume the job from last chunk written or the problem is my custom reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RestReader` must implement [ItemStream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html). This is the contract that stateful item readers should implement. The `ItemStream#update` method will be called at chunk boundaries to save any contextual data required to restart from the last checkpoint in case of failure.

Comment: Please can you provide some example of implementation? In the case of a RestReader what should be the implementation of open and update methods?

Comment: ok but I should call this itemstream methods inside read method? I can't find documentation or examples about itemstream

Comment: No, you just need implement them, spring batch will call them at the right lifecycle times. The documentation of item streams is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemStream